# How can I kill piped background processes?

Tags: linux, bash, pipe

Example session:

```
- cat myscript.sh 
#!/bin/bash
tail -f example.log | grep "foobar" &
echo "code goes here"
# here is were I want tail and grep to die
echo "more code here"

- ./myscript.sh

- ps
  PID TTY          TIME CMD
15707 pts/8    00:00:00 bash
20700 pts/8    00:00:00 tail
20701 pts/8    00:00:00 grep
21307 pts/8    00:00:00 ps
```

As you can see, tail and grep are still running.

---

Something like the following would be great

```
#!/bin/bash
tail -f example.log | grep "foobar" &
PID=$!
echo "code goes here"
kill $PID
echo "more code here"
```

But that only kills grep, not tail.

Comment: `kill -9 $PID` perhaps?

Comment: @AndersR.Bystrup That still only kills the `grep`, but with a different signal.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Although the entire pipeline is executed in the background, only the PID of the `grep` process is stored in `$!`. You want to tell `kill` to kill the entire job instead. You can use `%1`, which will kill the first job started by the current shell.

```
#!/bin/bash
tail -f example.log | grep "foobar" &
echo "code goes here"
kill %1
echo "more code here"
```

---

Even if you just kill the `grep` process, the `tail` process should exit the next time it tries to write to standard output, since that file handle was closed when `grep` exits. Depending on how often example.log is updated, that could be almost immediately, or it could take a while.

Answer (score 2):

you could add `kill %1` at the end of your script.

That will kill the `first` background created, that way no need to find out pids etc.

Comment: `kill %1` will kill the *first* job created, not the last one (although in the example, there is only one background job, so first and last are the same). `kill %%` or `kill %` would kill the current (i.e., most recently created) job.

Comment: This clearly does work, but does anyone know where it is officially document? I was hoping to read more about this, but there's nothing in `man kill` or anywhere else that I have found so far via Web search.

Comment: @SteveJorgensen Go [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55422125/9608759) or if that link does not work in the future, the documentation is in bash manual. `man bash` and search for `/jobspec`.