# What does percent sign % do in "kill %vmtouch"?

Tags: shell

I came across this [shell script](https://www.slideshare.net/JimmyMrdell/playlists-at-spotify-cassandra-summit-london-2013#slide32)

```
bash# while true; do
  vmtouch -m 10000000000 -l *head* & sleep 10m
  kill %vmtouch
done
```

and wonder how does the `kill %vmtouch` portion work?

I normally pass a pid to kill a process but how does %vmtouch resolve to a pid?

I tried to run portions of script seperately but I got
`-bash: kill: %vmtouch: no such job` error.

Comment: Different things depending on context; `${var%suffixpat}`, f/e, is something different. A title that identifies that context would be better; at first glance with the original title, one might expect this to be one of the many duplicates of [percent symbol in bash: What's it used for?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34951901/percent-symbol-in-bash-whats-it-used-for)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`%something` is not a general shell script feature, but syntax used by the `kill`, `fg` and `bg` builtin commands to identify jobs. It searches the list of the shell's active jobs for the given string, and then signals that.

Here's `man bash` searching for `/jobspec`:

> The  character  %  introduces  a job specification (jobspec).
>          Job number n may be referred to as %n.  A job **may also be referred to using a prefix of the name used to start it**, or using a substring that appears in its command line. [...]

So if you do:

```
sleep 30 &
cat &
```

You can use things like `%sleep` or `%sl` to conveniently refer to the last one without having to find or remember its pid or job number.

Answer (score 2):

You should look at the Job control section of the `man bash` page.  The character `%` introduces a job specification (jobspec). Ideally when you have started this background job, you should have seen an entry in the terminal

```
[1] 25647
```

where `25647` is some random number I used. The line above means that the process id of the last backgrounded job (on a pipeline, the process id of the last process) is using job number as `1`.

The way you are using the job spec is wrong in your case as it does *not* take process name of the background job. The last backgrounded is referred to as `%1`, so ideally your kill command should have been written as below, which is the same as writing `kill 25647`

```
vmtouch -m 10000000000 -l *head* & sleep 10m
kill %1
```

But that said, instead of relying the jobspec ids, you can access the process id of the background job which is stored in a special shell variable `$!` which you can use as

```
vmtouch -m whatever -l *head* & vmtouch_pid=$!
sleep 10m
kill "$vmtouch_pid"
```

See [Job Control Basics](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Job-Control-Basics.html) from the GNU bash man page.